# Unable to connect Google Cloud Build with Bitbucket Server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket, google-cloud-build, bitbucket-server

I have been trying to setup my Google Cloud Build with a Bitbucket Server that is running in a Compute Engine instance. In other words, they are inside of the same VPC, if I understood it correctly. I have created all the needed information, like HTTP Tokens and API Token from Google Cloud and Bitbucket Server side, but I keep getting a "Could not connect to Host" whenever I try to setup a new Host inside of Google Cloud Build.

I am really frustrated because I could not find any logs that point to Google Cloud Build and looking at my access logs from Bitbucket side, looks like it didn't reach Bitbucket at all.

Please, can someone help me out? I am trying to do this for a while and tried several things already and nothing works.

Looking forward for an answer or idea!

Regards,
Guilherme

Comment: Did you provide the correct parameter? Can you detail more what you did to achieve this? Your firewall rules and other parameter that can block the traffic

Comment: Hello @guillaumeblaquiere, thanks for replying me back. I have execute all the steps from this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-repos-from-bitbucket-server?hl=pt-br. I do have a Bitbucket server running in a Compute instance.